# Show files and contents of files created by my app to User in iOS in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, file

I am creating an OCR app where I am saving results of scans in files with this code.

```
let localFileName = String("file.rtf")
let text = String(“Scan result text”)

if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

    let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(localFileName)

    do {
        try text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
    }
    catch {}

    do {
        let text2 = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)

        print("Read from file \(text2)")
    }
    catch {}
}
```

This code is working and creating files somewhere and I am able to verify that this code is working. Now I want that files and their contents accessible to user of my app. How can I do that? Is there a way to create files in public directory?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller?language=objc

Comment: *"Now I want that files and their contents accessible to user of my app"* - accessible how? What do you want the user to be able to do and see?

Comment: User can see what files are generated and can also open that files and see what text is inside of that files.